# How to use Realm Swift Init

Tags: swift, realm

I am trying to use the init for Realm in Swift. I have tried the following

```
override init(value: AnyObject) { 
    super.init() 
    println("this is not called") 
} 

required init() { 
    super.init() 
    println("this is called") 
}
```

I want to be able to pass an object into the initializer, however, I can't get the first function to be called.

Comment: What does the code look like where you are trying to call this initializer?

Comment: Have you seen this issue? https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1849

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding `Object.init()` and `Object.init(_:)` are not yet supported in Realm Swift, but you can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1849 for updates!

Answer (score 35):

My solution in `Swift 3`

Custom initializer:

```
class Branches: Object {

    dynamic var key: String = NSUUID().uuidString
    dynamic var formattedAddress: String = ""
    dynamic var latitude: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var longitude: Double = 0.0


 convenience init(formattedAddress: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
    self.init()
    self.formattedAddress = formattedAddress
    self.latitude = latitude
    self.longitude = longitude
 }

 override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "key"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. self.init must be called for Realm object goodies to be completely safe.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my answer for `iOS 13`, `Swift 5`.

Being totally honest with you, I had no idea what I was doing, but I managed it to work by doing so:

```
class Account: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var balance: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var savings: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var available: Double = 0.0


    init(name: String, balance: Double){
    
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
        self.savings = 0.0
        self.available = balance
    
    }

    required init() {
        //fatalError("init() has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that I'm totally new with Swift (about 3 months top), and I don't know the consequences of doing that. But my project is working just fine. Everything is being saved and retrieved perfectly.

Comment: This is not safe, because re-implementing `self.init()` leads to unpredictable Realm behavior when using certain features.  See @Zhanserik's answer.